# data-synchronization of lists in an asynchronous process

Tags: java, salesforce, data-synchronization

In Salesforce each person has a unique id. When I push a list of people who aren't in Salesforce, a new list is asynchronously returned (could take hours) to me that is my list with the id row filled out. The rows of the new list aren't in the same order. How could I match the sent list with the returned list so that the unique id that was returned could be added to the sent list? Any  variety of data structures could be used. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Post some code?

The SOAP API [docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_create_saveresult.htm):

> The create() call returns an array of SaveResult objects. Each element
>   in the SaveResult array corresponds to the sObject[] array passed as
>   the sObjects parameter in the create() call. For example, the **object
>   returned in the first index in the SaveResult array matches the object
>   specified in the first index of the sObject[] array.**

The documentation & sample Java code of `create()` call: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_create.htm#SampleIntro

I you indeed have reordered results - file a bug with SF support. You could also follow up with simply querying for data `WHERE Id IN ...` but I strongly suspect it's something on your side (serializing & deserializing maps maybe?)